# Как реализовать web-службу с таймером?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Доброго времени суток!

Я создаю web-приложение на ASP.NET MVC SPA.
В нем есть собственное API, которое отдает данные в виде JSON.
Необходимо сделать так, что бы время от времени, данные брались с внешнего источника, независимо от того, обращается ли кто-то к web-приложению или нет. Другими словами нужно собирать данные по таймеру, и отправлять уведомление пользователям, например на email.

Вопрос в том, как мне реализовать web-службу с таймером?
Какие есть варианты? Как это делается правильно?
Можно ли это сделать через WCF, или он тоже будет работать тогда когда к нему обращаются?

Comment: Shad, спасибо за ответ!
Раньше как раз и делал 2-ым вариантом с помощью вин-сервиса, в этот раз просто выделяют только обычный хостинг для сайта, не где службу ставить...
1-ый очень не практичный вариант.
А не ли какой специальной надстройки на IIS?

Comment: @devEugene, не встречал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас возникла потребность в фоновой задаче, которая бы запускалась периодически (независимо от запросов к Web-приложению) и выполняла "полезную работу": сбор каких-то данных, рассылка уведомлений и т.д. Как и в большиснтве случаев, существует множество вариантов решения. Предложу пару, с которыми встречался на практике.

---

**1)** Фоновые потоки прямо в Web-приложении. В этом случае ваше приложени (MVC-сайт либо Web-служба) при старте запускает необходимые фоновые потоки, которые простаивают заданное количество времени, а по его истечении выполняют свою работу. После выполнения работы поток снова "засыпает" на заданный промежуток времени. Достоинства такого подхода:

- Относительно легкая реализация
- Не требуется создание отдельных приложений

Но есть и существенные недостатки:

- Дополнительная нагрузка на Web-приложение
- Повышение уязвимости Web-приложения (из-за необработанных исключений в потоках, например)

Если решите попробовать такой подход, обязательно ознакомтесь с этой статьей: [The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/). В ней описаны возможные риски и пример реализации (англ. язык).

---

**2)** Отдельное консольное приложение, выполняющее нужную задачу и запускающееся планировщиком по заданному расписанию (похожий вариант - создание своего Windows-сервиса). Плюсы:

- Разгрузка Web-приложения от дополнительной работы
- Возможность запуска на другой машине

Минусы:

- Необходимо создание отдельного приложения и его конфигурирование